# How to add text field and button in jasper report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a java struts project in which reporting is done through jasper reports. Report output can be pdf, csv, html.

Following is my jrxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jasperReport PUBLIC "-//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN" "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd">

<jasperReport name="cas" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30" >
<import value="java.util.Date"/>
<import value="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="F1" class="java.lang.String"></field>
    <field name="F2" class="java.lang.String"></field>
    <field name="F3" class="java.lang.String"></field>
    <field name="F4" class="java.lang.String"></field>

<pageHeader>
    <band height="117">
        <line>
            <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="553" height="1" />
        </line>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="553" height="25" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font fontName="Arial_Bold" size="16"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Sample report]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="15" width="553" height="20" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression ><![CDATA["Date: "+new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date())]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
```

The requirement is to add a text field and a date selector and a button. Clicking on button should show records according to date.

I have searched a lot but not able to found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you will have to use a sub-report option. This feature allows incorporating a report within another report, that is, one report can be a subreport of another. So, the dates will be displayed on the master report. And on clicking that record, the report for that particular date will be displayed.